# Registering/detecting an importer by file name extension

Tags: import

I've developed an importer and exporter for FreeSurfer's `MGH`/`MGZ` file format; the specific format isn't important, but I was wondering if there is a 'correct' way to tell *Mathematica* that file names ending with ".mgh" should be automatically imported using my MGH importer?

*Mathematica* obviously does this for its built-in importers (e.g., `Import["abc.csv"]` is equivalent to `Import["abc.csv", "CSV"]`), so it seems like it should be possible, but I haven't been able to find any information about this in *Mathematica*'s documentation.

One solution, which seems inelegant to me, is this:

```
Unprotect[Import];
Import[name_String /; StringMatchQ[name, __ ~~ ".mgh" ~~ EndOfString]] := 
  Import[name, "MGH"];
Import[name_String /; StringMatchQ[name, __ ~~ ".mgz" ~~ EndOfString]] := 
  Import[name, {"GZip", "MGH"}];
Protect[Import];
```

Is there a more principled way of going about this?

Comment: Have you read [this tutorial](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/tutorial/ImportingAndExportingOverview.html)?  It details how to develop Import/Export converters.  I don't know if it contains the information you're asking for, but it's the best place to look.

Comment: I've read all of those a couple times and they seem to be the only official source of info on getting forms like Import["abc.mgh", "MGH"] to work (using ImportExport`RegisterImporter). Unless I missed something there is no information about the auto-detection of file type in there, however.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can now be done using RegisterFormat from the Wolfram Function Repository.

https://resources.wolframcloud.com/FunctionRepository/resources/RegisterFormat

Answer (score 4):

I believe all you need to do is add your extension to the `ExtensionMappings.m` file in `` System`ConvertersDump`$FormatsDirectory ``.

Comment: This does solve the problem locally for my machine; however, the importer is part of a package/library that I would like to distribute, and this solution would require each library user to both have root privilege and go mucking around in their Mathematica systems directories. I'm looking for something that can be done at the time the package is loaded.

Comment: It's helpful to specify those details :) Your own idea is probably the best option, then, unless you want to do something hacky like Block[{System`ConvertersDump`ExtensionMappings=Join[{"*.myFormat"->"MYFORMAT"},Join@@System`ConvertersDump`GetExtensionMappings/@System`ConvertersDump`$FormatsDirectory,System`ConvertersDump`ExtensionMappings]},
System`ConvertersDump`ExtensionMappings]

Comment: Thanks, that is definitely closer to the kind of answer I was looking for, but it doesn't work. By the way, AppendTo[System`ConvertersDump`ExtensionMappings, "*.mgh" -> "MGH"] would seem to be sufficient, but either way that I do it, Import fails to infer the format of files ending with the extension.
Also, how can I find more documentation on these namespaces? As far as I can tell these are not documented anywhere...

Comment: Not documenting things is one of Mathematica's strongest features :P add //Trace to your import line and you can see what it does. Beware though, it's a lot of output. Usually easier to export that text and view it in a text editor.

Comment: You'll see ExtensionMappings doesn't get defined until Import is actually called. You may be able to define it globally and Protect it, though I'm not sure if that will work/is advisable.

Comment: Use double backticks to delimit inline code that contains backticks.  (See how I edited.)

Comment: @Szabolcs thanks!

Comment: It doesn't work for me either. I can see the mapping exists ("*.bbb"-> "BBB"), but it doesn't do me any good. `Import["file.bbb"]` does not get imported whereas `Import["file.bbb","BBB"]` does.

Comment: For the record, this is a terrible suggestion, and my answer above should just be used.