# Export Time-dependent STL Graphics

Tags: export, animation, mesh

I have recently found that Mathematica may export files (.stl) which may be used for Blender (3D pictures and animations). However, I am interested in mathematics visualization, and I suppose that when working with animations, I will need curves or surfaces which move according to mathematic equations. See for example the figures in the following video:

[Film *Dimensions*, Chapter 4](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Eef3twD0N94)

Since Blender does not seem to support high mathematics, it would be great to export somehow a time-dependent mesh. Is there something like this available?

Perhaps this question is more on Blender than on Mathematica. However any suggestion or idea will be welcome.

---

It may be helpful to consider the .mdd format mentioned [here](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/23349/importing-time-dependent-mesh). Is such format exportable from Mathematica?

Comment: Exporting multiple objects (each for a given time/state) is trivial. Would that already be useful? The animation would have to be put together in Blender, though. Inversely related: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/60292/131