# Make a .C3D file in Mathematica

Tags: list-manipulation, graphics3d, output-formatting, cdf-format, image-processing

I have two different groups of points in an excel file, which are captured by two different cameras from two different angles (Motion Capture Process). These points are extracted by using markers on a human body while he was walking.

Now I want to make a .cd3 file to be used in other software. Is it possible to make a .c3d file in MATHEMATICA?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Not by any built-ins that I am aware of. You might want to add sample data and file format specifications, but this sounds like quite a bit of work. Perhaps related: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/60292/131 with an *incredibly* cool answer from @Sjoerd.