# Is it possible to animate a bone or a skeleton fetched from Wolfram AnatomyData?

Tags: graphics3d, animation, anatomy

We can get a 3D bone with a simple command like this: `(ctrl+)Thigh ["Graphics3D"]`
[image]

or like this `(ctrl+)bone ["Graphics3D"]`
[image]

Can we animate these objects ? For example, make the thigh turn a circle, or even make the skeleton do a squat exercise ?

Thank you very much.

Comment: I think (as of now) the rotations need to be created manually. Here's an example similar to what you're asking. http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/AnatomyPlot3D.html#549131188

Comment: With respect to animating a skeleton, [this](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/60292) might be a useful starting point.

Comment: Quite useful, Thank you very much !!! @J. M.

Answer (score 7):

```
{femur, skeleton} = Interpreter[
       "ComputedAnatomicalStructure"][#][
     "Graphics3D"] & /@ {"left femur", "skeleton"};
```

This is quite **slow** to initialize and for any change to `ViewPoint` for `skeleton`

```
Manipulate[
 Show[bone, ViewPoint -> vp],
 {{bone, femur}, {femur, skeleton}},
 {{vp, Front, "View Point"},
  {Above, Below, Front, Back, Left, Right,
   {Above, Front}, {Above, Back},
   {Below, Front}, {Below, Back},
   {Left, Above}, {Right, Above},
   {Left, Below}, {Right, Below},
   {Left, Front}, {Right, Front},
   {Left, Back}, {Right, Back},
   {Above, Front, Left}, {Above, Front, Right}, 
   {Below, Front, Left}, {Below, Front, Right},
   {Above, Back, Left}, {Above, Back, Right},
   {Below, Back, Left}, {Below, Back, Right}}},
 SynchronousUpdating -> False]
```

[image]

Alternatively, you can set the `ViewPoint` to `{x,y,z}` and manipulate these variables

Answer (score 5):

I though I read something about you could not rotate them, but…

As far as manual animation, in V11 I was able to draw a bone with:

```
AnatomyPlot3D[Entity["AnatomicalStructure", "LeftFemur"]]
```

and I could animate it manually.

Also, looking at the `InputForm[]` of the result, shows that it is drawn with a `GraphicsComplex[]` and there is a `ViewPoint->` option, so you should be able to animate it programmatically.

Comment: Your code `AnatomyPlot3D...` didn't work on v11. I got these messages `EntityValue::nodat: Unable to download data. Some or all results may be missing.`  `AnatomyPlot3D::missmod: Unable to obtain a 3D model for Entity[AnatomicalStructure,LeftFemur].`

Comment: Sorry Alan...that worked on my V11.0 Mac ElCap...I have seen a bunch of `EntityValue[]` errors that are basically DB timeouts...sometimes re-running it will succeed...I assume these are infrastructure configuration issues in the back-end (that WRI support is working on)