# Anatomical movements

Tags: graphics3d, anatomy

```
AnatomyPlot3D[{Entity["AnatomicalStructure", "Humerus"], 
  Entity["AnatomicalStructure", "Radius"], 
  Entity["AnatomicalStructure", "Ulna"], 
  Entity["AnatomicalStructure", "Scapula"]}]
```

[image]

How can I move the humerus in the shoulder joint, while the radius and ulna stay attached? Subsequently, how to move the radius-ulna pair independently of the humerus? I'm aware that rotations will have to be used (e.g. 3 DOF for humerus), but I'm unaware how to set the attachment point from where the rotations will happen (shoulder joint and radioulnar joint for humerus and radius-ulnar pair respectively).

Comment: Look up `Rotate[g,θ,w,p]`.  Apply it to the elements `g` in `Cases[ap, {__, _[_GraphicsComplex, __]}, Infinity]`, where `ap` is the plot above.  You will need to use `Translate[]` as well.

Comment: There's an example in the documentation for AnatomyPlot3D that should get you somewhere; search for "Apply Rotate to anatomical structures".

Comment: [This](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/60292/how-to-build-a-bvh-a-motion-capture-file-format-player-in-mathematica) might be useful to import (sample) anatomical movement information.