# How to make Import recognize a new file extension?

Tags: import, data-format

I've written an [import converter](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/DevelopingAnImportConverter.html) for a custom file format, and it all seems to be working as expected, except for the fallback behavior with no arguments:

```
Import["C:\\Data\\samplefile.xxx"]

(*Import::infer: Cannot infer format of file samplefile.xxx. >> *)

(* Out[1]= $Failed *)
```

Does anyone know how I go about informing `Import` of the file extension so that it can process a file using the default converter from the filename alone (i.e., without an argument to specify the type)?

Comment: This is covered in a couple of places, but the most relevant is [here](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/60942/52). See the bottom of the last code listing in the answer.

Comment: @rcollyer Thanks for the tip. I've posted the relevant portion of the content that you linked as an answer here to make it easier to find, since it there is a lot of unrelated (but highly interesting) code in the other question.

Comment: Glad it works for you. It's unfortunately not pretty, but probably the best for now. It would be nice if adding to the extension mapping system file would work, but it never did for me. BTW @pinging only works if I already contributed to the comments on this page.

Comment: I agree with the reopen vote. It is not covered in detail in @SjoerdC.deVries' "duplicate" answer, in fact it is only given as a snippet of code with some undocumented functions as part of a much larger package concerning a much broader task with the overloading of `Import` as a nice supplement. This makes the problem hardly searchable, whereas the posed question here is both specific and general enough to be easily searchable and of interest to others.

Comment: @rcollyer Perhaps you gained some more inside knowledge about this since the question was asked.  Is the file format detected purely based on the extension, or also the file contents?  I believe the latter is the case. See `FileFormat`.  Finally, would overloading `FileFormat` be a better solution than overloading `Import`?

Comment: @Szabolcs unfortunately, I have not. I haven't had a chance to dig into that area.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

### New solution using RegisterFormat from Wolfram Function Repository:

```
ResourceFunction["RegisterFormat"]["BVH", <|"Extension" -> "bvh"|>]
```

### Original Post:

### Copy/paste from the excellent BVH package by @Sjoerd C. de Vries:

The code in this question ([Registering/detecting an importer by file name extension](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/51192/57)) did not work. Neither did the answer. Wolfram support could not provide a more elegant solution so far. We use a trick here. In fact we don't have any options, but we need to add the option part to the argument template to be slightly more specific overall than an existing one that would also match. In this way we get to be evaluated before the other one, otherwise we'd be shadowed.

```
ImportExport`RegisterImport["BVH", BVHImporter`BVHImport];
BVHImporter`BVHImport[filename_String] := BVHImporter`BVHGet[Import[filename, "String"]];

Unprotect[Import];

Import[name_String, opts___?OptionQ] :=
    Import[name, "BVH", opts] /; FileExtension[name] === "bvh";

Protect[Import];
```

Related tutorial from the documentation: [Developing an Import Converter](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/DevelopingAnImportConverter.html)

Answer (score 3):

Here's a nice trick. We can simply figure out how `FileFormat` works and write a little wrapper, which frees us from overloading `Import`:

```
withFileFormat[formatName_ -> fileExtensions_, expr_] :=

  Internal`InheritedBlock[{
    FileFormatDump`$FILEFORMATS,
    FileFormatDump`$FILEFORMATMATRIX
    },
   FileFormatDump`$FILEFORMATS =
    Append[FileFormatDump`$FILEFORMATS, formatName];
   FileFormatDump`$FILEFORMATMATRIX[formatName] =
    {
     formatName,
     False, False, False, False, False,
     "*." <> # & /@ fileExtensions,
     {}, None, {}
     };
   expr
   ];
withFileFormat~SetAttributes~HoldRest
```

Then we check it on `FileFormat`:

```
withFileFormat["SHELL" -> {"sh"},
 FileFormat["~/Desktop/Bugs.sh"]
 ]

"SHELL"
```

And if I had a definition for `"SHELL"` this *should* work:

```
withFileFormat["SHELL" -> {"sh"},
 Import["~/Desktop/Bugs.sh"]
 ]

Import::infer: Cannot infer format of file Bugs.sh.

$Failed
```

On the plus side this differs from the *default* behavior in 11.3 which is to import as `"Text"`.

Registering an alias for a new format will probably require more digging.

One noteworthy thing: if you drop the `` Internal`InheritedBlock `` this is literally just registering a new `FileFormat`.