# Import Converter as a Paclet

Tags: import, paclets

In short, I have a package that can load a proprietary device file-format. The underlying reading code is written in Java, packed into `.jar`, and in a Mathematica package, I can use some simple `JLink` wrapper functions to access the functionality.

Now, I would like to attach my code to Mathematica's `Import`, which is usually also trivial by employing `` ImportExport`RegisterImport ``. However, to make the importer always available, the `RegisterImport` code is [should be placed in](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/AutomaticLoadingOfImportExportConverters.html)

```
$UserBaseDirectory/SystemFiles/Formats/MyFormat/Import.m
```

For simplicity, assume the following fake package structure

```
MyFormat/
├── Java
│   └── reader.jar
├── Kernel
│   └── init.m
├── Import.m
├── PacletInfo.m
└── ReadingFunctions.m
```

In `ReadingFunctions.m`, I'm accessing the Java methods from the `jar` and provide high-level Mathematica functions for the binary file format. In `Import.m` I can use these functions and register a custom importer.

My questions are simple:

1. How can I set-up the `PacletInfo.m` so that the `Import.m` goes into the `Formats` directory and automatically loads the rest of the package when I try to import files?
2. Or should I use `Loading -> "Startup"` in the `PacletInfo.m` to make it available on a kernel start? But then, some unnecessary is always evaluated (e.g. loading of the `jar`) that I only need if I indeed use the importer in a session.

Are there other/better ways I haven't considered? I could start testing around, but my hope is that someone can give some hints.

**Bonus:** Do we have a better alternative to [this here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/65053/how-to-make-import-recognize-a-new-file-extension) for adding a file-extension so that it is automatically recognized by `Import`?

Comment: As for the bonus question: I suspect that there's more to file format detection than the file extension.  See `FileFormat`.  *Has anyone investigated if overloading `FileFormat` will affect how `Import` decides about the format?*

Comment: @GenericAccountName Do you have any hints regarding the main part of the question?

Comment: @Szabolcs I don't think overloading FileFormat is really possible for a user without breaking the rest of FileFormat. There currently isn't a user facing way to register a format with FileFormat at all. I will look into whether or not this is something we can add, which would eliminate the need for [this](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/65053/how-to-make-import-recognize-a-new-file-extension).. Sorry for reposting and deleting the comment, there was a typo and apparently you cannot edit comments (actually you can just perhaps only for a certain amount of time?)

Comment: @GenericAccountName Comments can be edited for 5 minutes. I think there's nothing wrong with deleting and re-posting if there were no responses to the comment.

Comment: @halirutan did you see my answer? Hopefully this helps, but let me know if you have any questions. I realize the one drawback is after the paclet is installed, you must load the paclet once manually before the import format is registered. After this happens once, Import can just be used like normal. Loading->"Startup" would be a hacky solution to this, I agree always being loaded is not ideal. I'm curious if anyone has an idea so that the $UserBaseDirectory stuff happens when PacletInstall[ ] is called.

Comment: Also check out https://github.com/WolframResearch/BioFormatsLink for another example, but this solution requires Needs[] to be called before using the formats

Comment: @halirutan here's a clean way to register these [formats](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/186822/38205). For what I do (and I do a *lot* of this for chemistry formats) I just have my ``ImportExport`Register<blah>`` occur when my package loads.

Answer (score 4):

@halirutan you can now register the format extension using this function from Wolfram Function Repository:

https://resources.wolframcloud.com/FunctionRepository/resources/RegisterFormat

Comment: Nice one! That might become handy some day. +1

Answer (score 2):

1. I don't think there's a way for PacletInfo.m to do this directly, but how about adding something in init.m like this before the `Get[]`:

   ```
   CreateDirectory[FileNameJoin[{$UserBaseDirectory, "SystemFiles", "Formats", "MyFormat"}]];
   Export[FileNameJoin[{$UserBaseDirectory, "SystemFiles", "Formats", "MyFormat", "Import.m"}], "RegisterImport...", "Text"];
   ```
2. Rather than registering the paclet functions as a format directly, make a small wrapper that does this, and register myImport instead:

   ```
   myImport[filePath_String, opts : OptionsPattern[]] :=
   Block[{..},
       Needs["MyFormat`"];
       ...
   ]
   ```

I noted in the comment above that there's no way to hook up to FileFormat (and thus get auto detection of extension/format the proper way) right now so the extension method from [this](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/65053/how-to-make-import-recognize-a-new-file-extension) post is the best bet in V11.3

Comment: Obviously you could CopyFile an Import.m or some such if you don't want to Export, but that seemed contained :)

Comment: I think you can get `FileFormat` to do stuff by registering a few things on the ``FileFormatDump`$FILEFORMATS`` and ``FileFormatDump`$FILEFORMATMATRIX``

Comment: @b3m2a1 I highly recommend not modifying these internal variables, it may have unintended consequences. I attempted to come up with a short guide to hack this for power users, but ran into too many issues to make this a feasible approach.

Comment: I think as long as you're smart about how you do it, it'll be fine. In general, Mathematica's not that strong as a system unless you make use of how open it is and play around with the internals. You just have to make sure to read the source code, though, and make sure everything you do accords with what the source does/expects.

Comment: In this case, the source is not available, so I'm not sure how you can do this without some guesses/assumptions. As the maintainer of FileFormat, what I can tell you is the order of FileFormatDump`$FILEFORMATS matters and we've decided it's not a good idea to modify these for now. I would suggest writing a wrapper that calls Import with the correct format if the extension or some other criteria about the file is met (magic number, heuristics, etc), and passes the data untouched to Import otherwise. Or even Unprotect Import, like the example I posted in my answer shows.

Comment: It’s Mathematica, so in general the source is always available. What do you mean “the order matters”? You guys use the order in which the formats are canonically defined?

Comment: Sorry but the source is not available. We have decided it would be better to improve format registration and document this properly rather than give implementation details in this case. All I can say is the order these formats are registered in is relevant, and since things were registered during kernel start, it would be best to avoid modifying these.

Comment: You can read the `DownValues` though and piece everything together that way. Are you preventing the `DownValues` from reordering...? That's fragile, but easy to manage. I haven't seen anything in the `DownValues` to suggest that it's *a priori* unmanageably difficult to register these formats. Good to know that there are subtle difficulties though :) I'll take these into account when I figure out how to modify all of this.

Comment: If you absolutely insist on such a hack in this direction, I suggest at least adding new formats to position -2 in $FILEFORMATS. Obviously with the disclaimer that this is not documented, thus unsupported and unexpected behavior _may_ occur. If you haven't figured out how ```FileFormatDump`$FILEFORMATMATRIX``` works, first get ```FileFormatDump`$FILEFORMATMATRIX[FileFormatDump`$FILEFORMATS[[-2]]]```, and set ```FileFormatDump`$FILEFORMATMATRIX["YourFormat"]``` with slight modifications from the example, ignoring the booleans.

Comment: I was hesitant to give such advice since I can't really elaborate much more on why. Hope this at least helps a little with your adventures in spelunking. I'm sure you've seen ```GeneralUtilities`PrintDefinitions```, but just in case you haven't it's pretty cool.

Comment: good to know I should add to position -2. I’ve figured out what many of the elements in the matrix rows mean, but I’ll be sure to dig them all up before permanently editing anything. I’ve been using `PrintDefinitionsLocal` for a while now (which is how I found these in the first place).